# React semantic ui card group warning - Encountered two children with the same key

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I put a map index in key elemental to have their own unique key.

Items looks have their unique key.

When I put address.id as key, same warning returns...

This is my code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import Generator from '../ethereum/generator'
import Betting from '../ethereum/betting'

function BettingIndex(props) {

    function renderBettings() {
        const items = props.bettings.map(async (address, index) => {
            const title = await Betting(address).methods.title().call()

            return {
                key: index,
                header: title,
                description: "description",
                fluid: true,
            }
        })

        return <Card.Group items={items}/>
    }

    return (
        <Layout>
            <h3>Open Bettings</h3>
            { renderBettings() }
        </Layout>
    );

}

BettingIndex.getInitialProps = async function() {
    const data = await Generator.methods.getDeployedBettings().call()
    return { bettings : data }
}

export default BettingIndex;
```

Comment: How does `props.bettings` looks like?

Comment: @Clarity
That is `data` in `BettingIndex.getInitialProps`.
Array.

Comment: The warning means that you either have duplicated address data or a few address elements with the same id, so you'd check what's returned from `getDeployedBettings`.

Comment: @Clarity
`props.bettings` has two elements. These two elements totally diffirent. When I put `address` in `header` without call `await Betting(address).methods.title().call()`, everything is Ok. Calling `await Betting(address).methods.title().call()` and `props.bettings.map(async (address, index) => {}` is looks problem.